# What is the difference between operatic, operative, and operational from Baudrillard's Simulacra and Simulation?

Tags: postmodernism, philosophy-of-culture, structuralism, hyperreality

The following is the conclusion from the chapter [Simulacra and Science Fiction](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4240082). I did not understand it, and such a specific categorization seemed unusual to me. I was hoping someone might be able to elaborate upon on it or explain it in a different way.

> "Between the operatic (the theatrical status of theatrical and
> fan­tastical machinery, the "grand opera" of technique) that
> corre­sponds to the first order, the operative (the industrial,
> productive status, productive of power and energy) that corresponds to
> the second order, and the operational (the cybernetic, aleatory,
> uncertain status of "metatechnique") that corresponds to the third or­der, all interference can still be produced today at the level of
> science fiction. But only the last order can still truly interest us."

Comment: The author suggests that in today's world the third order which deals with the networked social, cybernatic and uncertain aspects of technology, is the most intriguing and relevant for exploration in science fiction. In a sense SciFi has become a form or genre of metaphysical speculation of contemporary philosophy in a technology-advanced *hyperreal* society where simulacra has fully merged with simulation covering reality..